# How to count items where foreign key is repeated?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**How I can count items with same foreign key and still get acces to relationship data?**

I'm using **PHP** - **Laravel** - **Eloquent**, and have three tables: `User`, `User_items` and `items`.

`User_items` has three columns: `id`, `user_id` and `item_id`:

```
ID | user_id | item_id
0  | 5       | 2  
1  | 5       | 3  
2  | 5       | 8  
3  | 5       | 3
```

Let's say `items` also has three columns: `id`, `name` and `value`:

```
ID | Name    | Value
2  | Sword   | 500  
3  | Pickaxe | 250  
8  | Shovel  | 700
```

I want to count items with the same `user_id` and return item data from the `items` table. In order to get all of the user items, I'm using the following relationship:

```
    public function user_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User_items::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

Next, I want to get the names of these items and count them. I don't just want:

```
Sword
Pickaxe
Shovel
Pickaxe
```

I want, somehow, to get the results like this:

```
2 Pickaxe
1 Sword
1 Shovel
```

My `user_items` relationship, to get the data about an item looks like :

```
    public function item_data()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Items::class, 'id', 'item_id');
    }
```

Thats how I'm getting repeatable result:

```
return response()->json(["DATA" => $user->user_items->load('item_data')->toArray()], 201);
```

Example output

```
   "DATA":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "item_id":5,
         "created_at":"2019-06-04 08:44:08",
         "updated_at":"2019-06-04 08:44:08",
         "item_data":{  
            "id":5,
            "name":"Sword",
            "rarity":"good",
            "value":500,
            "image":"image.jpg",
            "color":"#3160ed",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      },
}
```

I want to add a row like `"count": 5` to the above output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon what you need is a many-to-many relationship between a user and an item.

I rename the tables like this for better naming convention: users, user_item, items.

```
class User
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)
    }
}
```

For each user to return the items and the number of items for each. You might do something like.

```
$items = $user->items()->select('items.*', 'count(items.id) AS items_count')
    ->groupBy('items.id')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

// From the controller, this array will be automatically converted to json.
return ['DATA' => $items];
```

You will have something like this. Not exactly the format you want, but I think it's better keep it this way.

```
[
    'DATA' => [
        {
            "id":5,
            "name":"Sword",
            "rarity":"good",
            "value":500,
            "image":"image.jpg",
            "color":"#3160ed",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            items_count: 1
        }
    ]
]
```